# Formula to make neon glow effect on a path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a neon light glow effect on a custom path like this image [image] I think it can be done using MaskFilter while painting the path on CustomPaint but I'm not sure exactly how to archive the effect like this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply Use :

```
dependencies:
  neon: ^0.1.0
```

---

```
import 'package:example/choose_font_page.dart';
import 'package:example/flickering_page.dart';
import 'package:example/glowing_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        accentColor: Colors.yellow,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[ChooseFontPage(), GlowingPage(), FlickeringPage()],
    ));
  }
}
```